# ¿Como ordenar alfabeticamente unos productos (Divs) con JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Tengo dos tipos de filtros, uno por categorías y funciona bien, pero no he logrado organizar alfabeticamente (A-Z), tome los datos y los agregué a un array y los ordené con `sort()` y se muestra ordenado el array, pero cuando muestro los divs, no.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<title>Products</title>
```

```
<!-- Menu footer -->
<div class="col-12 mb-4 toggle">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-12 gray-links text-center" id="tags">
      <div class="d-inline"><a class="sort bg-light p-2" href="">A-Z</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Products listing -->
<div class="col-12 m-0 p-0 pt-2" id="products">
    <div class="row m-0 p-0">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-9 ml-4 blue-links">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4 acer_predator_z35" id="computadores">
                    <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" ><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
                    <h6>Acer predator Z35</h6>
                    <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
                    <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
                </div>
                <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4 dell_infinityedge_5" id="computadores">
                    <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
                    <h6>Dell InfinityEdge 5</h6>
                    <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
                    <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
                </div>
                <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4 xiaomi_poco_3" id="telefonos_y_tablets">
                    <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
                    <h6>Xiaomi Poco 3</h6>
                    <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
                    <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
                </div>
                <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4 nikon_d3200" id="camaras_fotograficas">
                    <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
                    <h6>Nikon D3200</h6>
                    <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
                    <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
                </div>
                <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4 acer_predator_z55" id="computadores">
                    <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
                    <h6>Acer predator Z55</h6>
                    <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
                    <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
                </div>
                <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4 dell_infinityedge_7" id="computadores">
                    <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
                    <h6>Dell InfinityEdge 7</h6>
                    <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
                    <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
                </div>
                <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4 samsung_a21s" id="telefonos_y_tablets">
                    <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
                    <h6>Samsung A21s</h6>
                    <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
                    <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
                </div>
                <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4 gopro_max" id="camaras_fotograficas">
                    <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
                    <h6>GoPro Max</h6>
                    <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
                    <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 row justify-content-center mt-4">
                <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li class="page-item">
                          <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item">
                          <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 d-none d-md-block row">
            <div class="justify-content-center">
                <div class="blue-links">
                    <img class="img-fluid m-0 p-0" src="https://via.placeholder.com/270" alt="">
                    <h5><strong>Super vaccum</strong></h5>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo voluptates, laborum laboriosam vero adipisci saepe dicta? Quos, dolor, adipisci nobis labore vel, distinctio nemo rem, soluta praesentium ad itaque vero!</p>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <button class="btn btn-blue">Agregar al carro</button>
                    <h5>$35.000</h5>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#tags').find('a').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var products = $('#products').find('div.product');
            $(products).hide();
            var tipo = $(this).data('category');
            if(tipo == 'todos'){
                $(products).show();
            }else{
                $('#products').find('div.product#'+tipo).show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.sort').click(function(){
            var products = $('#products').find('div.product');
            $(products).hide();

            var products = $('#products').find('div > h6');

            let $arr = [];
            $(products).each((i, el) => {
                el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/ /g,"_");
                $arr.push(el.innerHTML)
            });

            $arr.sort()

            $(products).each((i, el) => {
              var products = $('#products').find('div.product.'+$arr[i]).show();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es mucho más simple de lo que parece, lo primero no deberías tener ids repetidos, usa atributos data si lo necesitas para categorizar los productos.

Con respecto a la posible solución, haciendo uso de un atributo "data-name" sustituyes las clases que le asignas a cada producto con su nombre y se lo asignas a este atributo.

Al div que contiene todos los productos le asignamos una clase para identificarlo.

Por último podrás ordenar los contenedores de productos vía javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sort').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var divList = $(".product");
    divList.sort(function(a, b) {
      return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('name').toLowerCase(), $(b).data('name').toLowerCase());
    });
    
    $(".product-container").html(divList);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Menu footer -->
<div class="col-12 mb-4 toggle">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-12 gray-links text-center" id="tags">
      <div class="d-inline"><a class="sort bg-light p-2" href="">A-Z</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Products listing -->
<div class="col-12 m-0 p-0 pt-2">
  <div class="row m-0 p-0">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9 ml-4 blue-links">
      <div class="row m-0 p-0 product-container">
        <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4 computadores" data-name="acer_predator_z35">
          <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
          <h6>Acer predator Z35</h6>
          <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
        </div>
        <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4" data-name="dell_infinityedge_5">
          <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
          <h6>Dell InfinityEdge 5</h6>
          <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
        </div>
        <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4" data-name="xiaomi_poco_3">
          <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
          <h6>Xiaomi Poco 3</h6>
          <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
        </div>
        <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4" data-name="nikon_d3200">
          <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
          <h6>Nikon D3200</h6>
          <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
        </div>
        <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4" data-name="acer_predator_z55">
          <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
          <h6>Acer predator Z55</h6>
          <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
        </div>
        <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4" data-name="dell_infinityedge_7">
          <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
          <h6>Dell InfinityEdge 7</h6>
          <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
        </div>
        <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4" data-name="samsung_a21s">
          <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
          <h6>Samsung A21s</h6>
          <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
        </div>
        <div class="product col-xl-3 col-sm-4 col-5 mb-4" data-name="gopro_max" id="camaras_fotograficas">
          <a href="producto.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/165" alt=""></a>
          <h6>GoPro Max</h6>
          <h4 class="text-blue">$35.000</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-blue"><small>Agregar al carro</small></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

> He simplificado tu código para que se vea mejor la respuesta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, excelente. Tomo en cuenta tu sugerencia.